# Angular CDK context menu - How do I catch the cdkContextmenuTriggerData from the cdkMenu template?

Tags: angular, angular-material, contextmenu, angular-cdk

I need to pass data within the context menu dynamically. `cdkContextmenuTriggerData` does the work but I am confused about how to catch this data within cdkMenu.

Here is my code -

```
<ng-template #menu>
  <div cdkMenu>
    <button cdkMenuItem>Edit</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<div [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="menu" [cdkContextMenuTriggerData]="variable">Right click on me..</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that you pass to the `cdkContextMenuTriggerData` input is basically passed through to the `[ngTemplateOutletContext]`. More info about setting and accessing the context in the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#description).

So it can be accessed using the `let-` keyword in the scope of the template (more docs about structural directives and keyword itself [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand)).

Considering your `variable` looks something like this:

```
let variable: { $implicit: { value: 'SomeValue' } }
```

You should be able to access it like so:

```
<ng-template #menu let-passedContext>
  <div cdkMenu>
    <button cdkMenuItem>Edit {{passedContext.value}}</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here's a [sample stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/afrkch).